# Mysql no me valida correctamente el where (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT LOT.id_lote,PRO.producto FROM productos_lotes LOT LEFT JOIN productos PRO ON PRO.id_producto = LOT.id_producto WHERE LOT.id_lote = '32we'
```

Donde en mi base de datos tengo id_lote = '32' no '32we' sin embargo me muestra el resultado de '32'

Mi base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El campo `id_lote` es `String` o `Int`?

Comment: ¿Qué estructura tiene tu tabla? La puedes obtener mediante la consulta `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;`  Sería bueno que agregues esa información a la pregunta. Ejecuta también estas dos consultas directamente en el SGBD: Por un lado esta: `SELECT * FROM productos_lotes WHERE id_lote='32';`  y por otro lado esta: `SELECT * FROM productos_lotes WHERE id_lote='32we';` y compara ambos resultados. Ten en cuenta que tu consulta es un JOIN, verifica que no tienes confusión con las tablas. Y si `id_lote` es INT ten en cuenta que no deberías poner comillas simples en la consulta para el valor 32

Comment: gracias amigo, la solucion fue quitarle las comillas ya que era un campo int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una norma en el estándar SQL que deberías respetar: **en la consultas, los valores numéricos van sin comillas**.

Si usas comillas, el SGBD hará una [conversión implícita](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), que funcionará en algunos casos y en otros no, dejando por tanto el funcionamiento de tu código al azar. Como programador, debes tener en mano tu código, siendo siempre cuidadoso con los tipos. Significa que si el valor `32`  es un entero, debes verificarlo, limpiarlo y lo que haga falta, para tener al final esto:

```
SELECT 
    LOT.id_lote,
    PRO.producto 
FROM productos_lotes LOT 
    LEFT JOIN productos PRO ON PRO.id_producto = LOT.id_producto 
WHERE LOT.id_lote = 32
```

El error aquí es que:

- Se te ha colado un valor `32ew`. Entonces, debes preguntarte por qué se ha colado ese valor y debes impedirlo.
- Estás escribiendo una consulta que fuerza una conversión de tipos. Si `id_lote` es INT no debes abandonar el código al azar escribiendo ingenuamente tu consulta así: `WHERE laColumnaNumerica='elValorNumerico'` sino aplicar rigor en tu código, escribiendo así: **`WHERE laColumnaNumerica=elValorNumerico`**

Tu código funcionaba porque en la conversión implícita, el SGBD no suele tener problemas cuando la cadena empieza por un número, él lo convierte a la parte numérica de esa cadena, por ejemplo:

```
select 32+'32we'  as sum;
```

Dará como resultado `64`. La consulta sumará `32+32`.

Pero esto:

```
select 32+'we32'  as sum;
```

Dará como resultado `32`, porque en este caso el resultado de la conversión implícita de la cadena fue `0` .

La conversión implícita es problemática a veces con cadenas largas, por lo que en ningún caso debes dejar tu código al azar.

Comment: Amigo gracias por tu interes y tu respuesta, aunque no era necesario lo de "ingenuo" ; marque tu respuesta como la correcta porque a tienes razon debi considerar el tipo de campo INT, y no es que no haya validado el 32we si no que de casualidad al escribir 32 se me escapo el we y note que igual me detectaba el id del item. Gracias por tu respuesta +1

Comment: @IntruzO ten en cuenta que las preguntas/respuestas están orientadas a ayudar a futuros usuarios con problemas similares. Lo de *ingenuo* no está de más porque de hecho veo muy a menudo consultas con datos de tipo numérico puestos entre comillas `''`